# Django segmentation fault

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

When I try to start 'python manage.py runserver', I endup with 'Segmentation Fault'. But, on repetitive try, server gets up and running.

Please note, I get below error in newly installed Windows 10 machine. With all other same settings, I am able to run this project successfully in another machine running with older windows version.

May I know what could be issue in this and why it succeeds on repeated try.

EDIT: Here's the link for full log

[Error log file](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AsvKpea0PlWjaYUw8-5IrSkXFSE)

Comment: Can you please add the full trace formatted as it occurs in your shell?

Comment: Added link for log file.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have installed another (newer?) version of python in your new windows.

In this case you need to delete all `__pycache__` folders within your source tree. The cached code is not compatible with your current interpreter.

I would also recommend to recreate your virtual environment if you use dependencies that rely on underlying C libraries.

Comment: I am using virtual environment. I had initially installed  python version 3.6.4 and got this error. So, downgraded to 3.6.3 and have been facing the same issue. I tried deleting pycache and still face the issue. Needed  to start multiple times to avoid seg fault and get server running

Comment: Have you recreated the environment?

Comment: Yes, I recreated. Didnt help.

Comment: I was facing this issue in Django 1.10 with Windows 10. Upgrading to Django 2+ fixed this error. Thanks.